# GitHub Pages Deployment Failure with my DocC project

Tags: swift, xcode, git, github, docc

I'm trying to push DocC to my GitHub Pages, I'm following tutorials on DocC documentation.
What I'm done till now is in my SPM directory I'm using these commands in terminal:

1. xcodebuild docbuild -scheme (schema-name) -derivedDataPath (doccarchive-file)
   -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=(simulator name)'
2. $(xcrun --find docc) process-archive transform-for-static-hosting (doccarchive-file)
   --output-path (docs-directory in my project) \
   --hosting-base-path (https://rezamagnet.github.io/RKBreadCrumb here I just using **RKBreadCrumb**)

and source of GitHub Pages is **main** branch and **docs** directory.

so everything works with these commands and I get my doccarchive and pushing it to my repository but GitHub gives me a failure, when I click on failure message it shows me this:
[image]

here is my GitHub repository [link](https://github.com/rezamagnet/RKBreadCrumb)

Answer (score 0):

I follow up the failure reason in this path:
**Jobs -> build from Actions tab**  on my GitHub repository

I noticed I'd added a Dependency but after that I removed that, but don't removed git cache that cause my problem.

I check this command on my terminal:

`git submodule status`
[image]

I notice there is an error in there, so I clear cache in my worktree:
`git rm -r --cached .`

then push again, and everything works well.